# Большое целое число с фиксированным значением выделенной памяти

Tags: c#, числа, biginteger, выделение-памяти

мне необходимо большое целое число с фиксированным значением выделенной памяти. Например, под это число я хочу выделить строго 128 байт. При этом с этим числом нужно совершать простые арифметические операции: сложение, вычитание, возведение в степень. Просто BigInteger из System.Numerics мне не подходит, так как он динамически выделяет память под числа.

Как быть?

Comment: а пользоваться массивом байт не пробовали?

Comment: *Например, под это число я хочу выделить строго 128 байт.* Да не вопрос, выделите и храните. А для проведения вычислений преобразуйте его в *BigInteger из System.Numerics* (а результат - соответственно обратно). Или надо в принципе исключить любую возможность динамической работы с памятью?

Comment: Нет, не пробовал. Попробую реализовать - отпишусь.

Comment: @Akina именно так

Comment: @Monomax не совсем понимаю, что Вы имеете ввиду. Мне нужно одно большое число, в то время как массив это массив. Если я из него пытаюсь сделать число BigIntger, то оно всё равно будет управлять памятью динамически

Comment: Не понимаю, в чём проблема использовать BigInteger. Эта структура неизменяемая сама по себе. Каждая операция, будь то сложение или деление, будет создавать новый экземпляр BigInteger, то есть занового выделять память. Если вам прям кровь из носа нужно, чтобы вот прям сейчас выделить ровно 16 байт и дальше вообще ни разу не выделять память и работать только с этим массивом, то пилите свой класс, который это и будет делать. Данная задача слишком специфична.

Comment: Лучше, если вы чуть уточните, что именно хотите получить. Пока смахивает на то, что у вас какое-то очень жесткое ограничение на потребление памяти и при этом вы очень частно проводите операции с эти числом, что сборщик мусора не успевает уничтожать массив, который в этой структуре находится.

Comment: @John я хочу сделать небольшой графический редактор для формулы Таппера. При этом K в этой формуле обновляется сразу при изменении изображения путём прибавления (или вычитания) к нему 2^N (закрашивание одной клетки). Проблема в том, что если 2^N > K, то это происходит медленно. Проблема решается, если закрасить самую последнюю клетку (2^1082) - остальные после этого закрашиваются быстро. Поэтому мне и показалось, что проблема в выделннии памяти для BigInteger (именно его я использую сейчас). Мне нужно, чтобы подвисаний не было, при этом костылять не хочется.

Comment: Судя по описанию у вас там столько костылей что мама не горюй!

Comment: При использовании BigInteger возникает большая нагрузка на сборщик мусора, что может приводить к тормозам. Помогает включение серверного GC. Но это именно освобождение памяти. А выделение памяти в .NET происходит мгновенно: просто сдвигается указатель в управляемой куче. Так что сомневаюсь, что ваша проблема решится, если бы BigInteger был не иммутабельный, а изменяемый тип.

Comment: Либо пишите собственную библиотеку для длинной арифметики, либо поищите готовую. Вот, [например](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BigInteger/) - пишут, что быстрее нативной.